# Oracle SQL Developer version 22.2.1

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

How do i import connection (json) file into oracle sql developer 22.2.1? I do use sql developer & did had options to import & export connections earlier but no options found in 22.2.1 version.

I don't find import options under connection tab also under view connection options. Is this a bug?

Comment: It's still there, if you don't see it it sounds like something is corrupt with your current install (connections.json file)

Comment: i'm using Mac M1

Comment: i'm using Mac M1 , i did downloaded correct version . no errors on installation .

Comment: delete the hidden sqldeveloper folder under your mac user ($HOME/.sqldeveloper) and try starting it again

Comment: Tried it but didn;t help

Comment: please update your question with more details, include screenshots of the UI, post contents of your log panel, etc.

Answer (score 1):

In the Connections pane, right click on the "Oracle connections" item and you should see the "Export connections..." menu item, at least it's what I see here, version 22.2.1.234 Build 234.1810 on Apple M1 box too.